# Difference between RxJava2 Completable.fromAction() vs Completable.fromCallable()?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

When should we use `Completable.fromAction()` and when should we use `Completable.fromCallable()` Is there a specific Usecase

From the documentation it seems that both do the same thing and it is hard to notice the difference between them.

**Completable.FromAction**
[image]

**Completable.fromCallable**
[image]

Answer (score 7):

There really isn't any difference. Here's the code:

```java
public final class CompletableFromAction extends Completable {

    final Action run;

    public CompletableFromAction(Action run) {
        this.run = run;
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(CompletableObserver observer) {
        Disposable d = Disposables.empty();
        observer.onSubscribe(d);
        try {
            run.run();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Exceptions.throwIfFatal(e);
            if (!d.isDisposed()) {
                observer.onError(e);
            } else {
                RxJavaPlugins.onError(e);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (!d.isDisposed()) {
            observer.onComplete();
        }
    }

}
```

```java
public final class CompletableFromCallable extends Completable {

    final Callable<?> callable;

    public CompletableFromCallable(Callable<?> callable) {
        this.callable = callable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(CompletableObserver observer) {
        Disposable d = Disposables.empty();
        observer.onSubscribe(d);
        try {
            callable.call();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Exceptions.throwIfFatal(e);
            if (!d.isDisposed()) {
                observer.onError(e);
            } else {
                RxJavaPlugins.onError(e);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (!d.isDisposed()) {
            observer.onComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

So the code is exactly the same. I think they both exist mostly for convenience - if you already have a `Callable` you want to wrap in a `Completable`, you can just use it directly. Same if you have an `Action`, or a `Runnable` (`Completable.fromRunnable` also exists). If only one existed, you'd have to do a little bit of extra work to convert one to the other.

Sources:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/completable/CompletableFromCallable.java

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/completable/CompletableFromAction.java

Answer (score 5):

Key (and the only) difference for me is when you look into actual difference of Action0 vs Callable those two work with:

```
public interface Action0 extends Action {
    void call();
}
```

vs

```
public interface Callable<V> {
    /**
     * Computes a result, or throws an exception if unable to do so.
     *
     * @return computed result
     * @throws Exception if unable to compute a result
     */
    V call() throws Exception;
}
```

Basically, if your logic returns nothing (which is exactly the thing in case of Callable), you better go with `Completable.fromAction` for cleaner code.